# Insert blank based on first digit of line

Tags: awk, sed

**Input**:

```
3abdce    
412ae3    
21dege
```

**Expected Output** - starting digit of line is removed and a blank inserted based on the offset specified by that digit

```
abd ce
12ae 3
1d ege
```

I can only remove the first character:

```
sed 's/^.\{1\}//g' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v FS="" '{ print substr($0,2,$1), substr($0,$1+2) }' file
```

- `$1` - points to the 1st *figure* value (slice size)

---

The output:

```
abd ce  

12ae 3  

1d ege
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk` as it supports empty `FS` and `OFS`

```
awk -v FS="" -v OFS=""  '{gsub($($1+1),"& ");gsub(/^./,"")}1' inputfile
abd ce
12ae 3
1d ege
```

Here, `FS` and `OFS` are set to blank and two `gsub` functions are used to to the required search and replace operation.

Answer (score 1):

this one should do the trick:

```
awk '{  split($0, a, ""); print substr($0, 2, a[1])" "substr($0, 2+a[1]) }' yourfile
```

Output:

```
abd ce 
12ae 3
1d ege
```

Comment: Thank you so much everybody,
@PS, I do not have gawk

Comment: @Sundeep, I am more used to awk or sed

Comment: What you prefer m8. Its a free world :)

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is okay

```
$ perl -F -lane 'print @F[1..$F[0]], " ", @F[$F[0]+1..$#F]' ip.txt
abd ce
12ae 3
1d ege
```

- `-F -lane` split each line on empty string, so each character is a field, saved in `@F` array
- Then print as required, indexing starts from `0`